Sleeping for a random amount of time in a stored procedure
A vendor application we're using utilizes multiple processes (not threads) spread across multiple computers, one for each processing core available. When asked for a batch of calculations, the application distributes the load between these engines, which then go to the database for additional details necessary to perform the computations.
As we add more cores -- and engines -- the simultaneous rush to the database causes a load spike so big, some engines start getting the ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred error, which causes them to crash (I know, it shouldn't, but we cannot fix the vendor's code). For example, with the engine-count of 1386, about 300 engines dump cores, because the 16-core Oracle server cannot cope...
There is no official way to cause the application to stagger these engine-initializations...
But the first thing each engine is doing is invoke the same stored procedure -- which updates the same table -- and I'm wondering, if I can alter it to perform the staggering: cause each engine to sleep for random number of milliseconds.
What would the SQL snippet for this look like? Our servers run Oracle-19...

You can't do this with SQL, but you can with DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP(), combined with DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE().

Could you provide the actual code snippet suitable for an Oracle stored procedure -- whatever language that would be?

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_SESSION.html#GUID-AF3D28D8-E194-48D0-ADA6-887BFC8CB1A4

There are numerous stored procedure examples in the Oracle documentation.

I know, how to write stored procedures. I'm asking, how to sleep for a random number of milliseconds here. Thanks!

@MikhailT. the documentation link I provided gives you all that information ;)

No, it does not, @Ditto. One can deduce it from there, but citing a link only is not a proper answer. And milliseconds aren't documented there at all -- I'm afraid, that just means it is not possible.

Argument is "number of seconds. Documentation also says: "The smallest increment can be entered in hundredths of a second; for example, 1.95 is a legal time value." If that's good enough for you (because 1 hundredth of a second is 10 milliseconds and you didn't say what "millisecond" exactly means in your case), do the math.

@MikhailT.  correct, citing a link is not a proper answer .. which is why I didn't post it as a separate answer . it's a comment to support this answer ... all the information you need is there.
